# How should I configure /etc/network/interface to make Proxmox node use an iface trunk?

Tags: networking, debian, proxmox

On a proxmox node I have the current `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eno1 inet manual

iface eno2 inet manual

iface eno3 inet manual

iface eno4 inet manual

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet dhcp
    bridge-ports eno1
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
    bridge-pvid 1
#Connected to switch's access port tagged with vlan 100

auto vmbr2
iface vmbr2 inet manual
    bridge-ports eno2
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
    bridge-vlan-aware yes
    bridge-vids 1 100 <bunch of vlans here>
#Trunk

auto vmbr3
iface vmbr3 inet manual
    bridge-ports eno3
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
    bridge-vlan-aware yes
    bridge-vids <other vlans here>
#other trunk
```

As you can see:

- `vmbr1` is a bridge on `eno1` interface which is connected to a switch's access port and tagged with vlan 100. It gets an IP through DHCP, this is the IP of the Proxmox node.
- `vmbr2` is a bridge on `eno2` interface which is connected to the same switch's to a trunk port. Among other vlans, this trunk carries vlan 100 as well.
- `vmbr3` is a bridge on `eno3` interface which is connected to another switch.

`eno3` and `eno4` are 10 GBbps ethernet interfaces and they are getting extremely hot. As I don't need 10GBps, in order to lower the power consumption and overall temperature, I would like to:

- make `vmbr1` use `eno2` interface (as the trunk already carries vlan 100)
- make `vmbr3` use `eno1` interface (in order to free the `eno3` 10Gbps interface)
- disable `eno3` and `eno4` interfaces (using a motherboard jumper)
- remove cable which was initially connected to `eno1`
- plug cable which was initially connected to `eno3` into `eno1`

As I'm not used to `/etc/network/interfaces` file configuration, and as this involves the interface providing to the proxmox node, I do not want to mess things up...

Could you please confirm that this is feasible (or if does not make sense and thus I should rather try to find another solution) and that the following configuration is correct (and correct it if it is not) ? it would be a great help.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eno1 inet manual

iface eno2 inet manual

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet dhcp
    bridge-ports eno2
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
    bridge-vlan-aware yes
    bridge-vids 1 100
#Previously connected to switch's access port tagged with vlan 100 using the trunk

auto vmbr2
iface vmbr2 inet manual
    bridge-ports eno2
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
    bridge-vlan-aware yes
    bridge-vids 1 100 <bunch of vlans here>
#Trunk

auto vmbr3
iface vmbr3 inet manual
    bridge-ports eno1
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
    bridge-vlan-aware yes
    bridge-vids <other vlans here>
#Another trunk
```